# How to add CLI to C# WPF project?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have c# WPF project and now I need to add c++ support. I know that it is possible by CLI implementation like a bridge.

I found this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019

But there is no words about how to integrate CLI to my C# project.

I thought that I need to create `.h` + `.cpp` files like CLI, but when I click `Add -> New Item` there is no C++ choice

How to start with it?

Comment: 1. Create a new C++/CLI project in your solution. 2. Add this project as reference to your C# project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to create C++/CLI for UWP projects and pretty sure WPF does almost the same way.

First of all, run Visual Studio Installer, go to "Desktop C++ Development" and make sure you have everything related to C++/CLI at "installed" state (because C++/CLI is usually not included into default set).

Then add a new project (as C++/CLI gate can not be a part of the same WPF or UWP project), you could find appropriate class lib in the templates tree under "C++ -> CLR"

Then you should reference your C++ staff (DLL, whatever) at the created C++/CLI project, and reference the C++/CLI project in the main WPF project.

You can try this as a starting point in case you stuck:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I have a good example of how to use native C++ components in managed applications: [NativeWPF](https://github.com/Grandbrain/NativeWPF).

The preferred way to do this is to add a new assembly with CLI support to the solution. In this project, you should write all your unsafe C++ classes, as well as C++/CLI code, which is the link between managed C# code and unmanaged C++. After that, you should add a reference to this project in your WPF application.

C++/CLI has a slightly different syntax, I recommend referring to the official Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp).